# Save and read string of floats one dataframe cell

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to save to csv file the following data frame :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
data = np.random.uniform(0,1,100)
Data = ['name', data]
df = pd.DataFrame(Data, columns=['name','data'])
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

But I get the error : `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 1), indices imply (2, 2)`

How can I save a string in one dataframe cell ? Will it be readable afterwards ?

Comment: Hi! it's not clear what you want to do. You want to create a dataframe like this
`df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name'])`?

Comment: I want the dataframe to have two columns, one withe the header : 'name', and the value 'name' (sorry redundant..), and the second column with the header : 'data' with value that is the string data created before.

Comment: Ok then Serge's answer is what you are looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataFrame constructor `pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)` expects the data to be passed in rows.

IIUC, you want to pass it in columns. Then you should use a different constructor and pass a dictionary indexed by the column names:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': name, 'data': data})
```

It gives:

```
    name      data
0   name  0.789336
1   name  0.112033
2   name  0.948779
3   name  0.931610
4   name  0.451328
..   ...       ...
95  name  0.844731
96  name  0.336140
97  name  0.727445
98  name  0.987609
99  name  0.663700

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```